# When to create a new commit on a feature branch?

Tags: git

When working on a new user story, I create a feature branch from the master branch.

On the feature branch, I create a new commit,

- when I think my work is ready to be pushed to GitHub to be review, or
- when I amend something in the current commit, either after i realize it myself, or receive a request for change from code reviewers

Now I wonder if there are other cases when I'd better create a new commit.

For example, when the user story for a feature branch can be divided into very small sub-problems.

- Is it better to group the work for different sub-problems into different commits, than to create a single commit containing the work for all the sub-problems? Will the former way make it easier for code reviewer or me later on to read and understand the work done on the user story?
- When I later modify my work already committed, based on requests for change from code reviewers or on my own realization of need for improvement, shall I also create different commits based on changes for different sub-problems?

Comment: 1. One commit = one *smallest*, but *logically complete* change. 2. In your topic branch you may use `git rebase` until you will have work done. After that you may submit a pull request.

Comment: @0andriy: Thanks. I am not sure what you suggest in " In your topic branch you may use git rebase until you will have work done."  So how is `git rebase` used in the context of my post? Thanks.

Comment: While you are working on topic, master branch could be advanced somehow. Instead of merging back the master, you just run `git fetch origin master:master; git checkout topic/branch-wip; git rebase master`.

Answer (score 3):

You may be thinking about too many things at once in relation to commits and reviews here.  Reviews happen at the *feature* level.  Commits are much much more granular than that.

Think of creating commits like hitting CTRL + S on a document.  You do that so you don't lose any of your existing work, either due to your working on it at 3AM, or due to your cat jumping on your keyboard and resting on the Backspace key.  In essence, you want to **commit early and commit often.**

How you break the work up for review is a decision you'll need to talk over with your team, since each team has a different flavor that they like to go about when working.

Comment: Thanks. If you create commit frequently and randomly and possibly in the middle of working on a minimal subproblem, how would you write the commit comment for you or code reviewers later on to figure out which commit contains some specific work which you or code reviewers want to look up?

Comment: That depends on your preferences, honestly.  My personal philosophy is to commit when I feel confident that the work I've got done in that commit can compile (not necessarily pass tests), and represents a good mental stopping point for my efforts.  If I need to change the commit message for an individual commit, I can always interactive-rebase and rewrite the messages *there*, but I've never really had an issue with coworkers or other reviewers inspecting *commit by commit*; it was always the amalgam of commits they looked at in review.

Comment: " it was always the amalgam of commits they looked at in review", do you mean that your code reviewers always look at a single view which is the accumulation of all the commits on your feature branch, instead of looking at individual commits?

Comment: Yes.  Review tools often look at the tip of the branch when reviewing, and the tip of your branch would contain the entire history of all of your commits done on that branch which differ from your requested merge point (say, master).